# Call Phone number from Android Source code, with default calling program

Tags: android

When I am making a call to a phone number from my program with following code

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0705352951"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

I get the question what program I will use to do the phone call. What I want is that my program is only using the default one on the phone, and skip the question, is it a way to do this?

Comment: it will use default dialped of a phone

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

to your manifest.xml

you might check this out: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/call-a-number-directly-from-an-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is using an implicit intent that asks for an app that can answer the CALL action. If several are found, the system will ask the user.

To avoid this phase, you have to resolve the intent yourself and use an **explicit** intent.

Typically, you'll do something like:

```
int flag = PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY;
List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, flag);

// This gets you a list. Typically you'll want the first item.
// However, from the doc, it is unclear if the first item is the best item or the chooser intent
ActivityInfo actualInfo = matches.get(0).activityInfo;

// Then you can create a ComponentName to make the intent explicit
intent.setComponentName(new ComponentName(actualInfo.packageName, actualInfo.name));

// and finally start your activity
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean that when you click on the button to make the call it opens a popup to choose the default application ? 
So you have to click one time on the default dialer icon and click below to "still using this application" or something similar, and the popup won't show up again ! 
Hope that it will help someone.